# Comparing a tuple of a pair to a list of tuple pairs

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-3.6

So I am working on this programming homework and I am currently stuck on comparing the pairs of values in one tuple to the tuple pairs in a list.

The pairs are basically x and y coordinates and I need to find the closest one from the list to the tuple pair. As an example, given the point `(-4, 3)` and the list `[(10, 6), (1, 7), (6, 3), (1, 9)]`, the closest one would be `(1, 7)`.

These numbers always changes with a randoming part of the programming but the the above is defined as a function. Here is the whole thing:

```
def nearest(point, more_points):
    '''
    Finds the nearest point to the base point
    '''
    (x, y) = point
    for i, j in more_points:
        a = math.fabs(x - i)
        tempI = i
        b = math.fabs(y - j)
        tempJ = j
        tempA, tempB = a , b
        if min(tempA) <  a:

point = () 
my_points = []
c = 0
lpoint = list(point)
while c < 2:
     lpoint.append(random.randrange(-5,5,1)) # generate the "point"
     c += 1
tpoint = tuple(lpoint)
c = 0
colx = [] # x points
coly = [] # y points
# generate the points
while c < 4:
    colx.append(random.randint(0,10))
    coly.append(random.randint(0,10))
    c += 1

my_point = list(zip(colx,coly))
print(my_point)
the_nearest = nearest(tpoint,my_point)
print(the_nearest)
```

What I am trying to do is to take the x,y in the point and then take the "other" point and get the difference and then use that to find the "nearest" but I lost and I am stuck. The focus is on the user defined function.

Comment: Can you edit your code to make proper indentation? Not sure about what is in the function and what is not.

Comment: @FunkySayu sorry not used to using stackoverflow but just did it

Comment: There is also a missing statement after the `if min(tempA) < a:`

Comment: yeah i know that but im keeping that empty because im stuck on what i should do @FunkySayu

Comment: You could try making a list that records the distance from each of the other points to the given point. Then find the argmin of that list. A very useful package is numpy, which has a function called argmin. (Also you can make things a lot easier if you record the points as an numpy array.)  - Have a look at the quickstart tutorial of numpy if you're not familiar with it: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html

Comment: I dont know if the professor is allowing us to use other imports other than like math and random @FabianYing

Comment: Calculate the distance between two points properly: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the following function calculate the distance within 2 points:

```
def distance(point_a, point_b):
    """Returns the distance between two points."""
    x0, y0 = point_a
    x1, y1 = point_b
    return math.fabs(x0 - x1) + math.fabs(y0 - y1)
```

You can iterate over all points and find the minimum distance:

```
def nearest(point, all_points):
    closest_point, best_distance = None, float("inf")
    for other_point in all_points:
        d = distance(point, other_point)
        if d < best_distance:
             closest_point, best_distance = other_point, d
    return closest_point
```

Although I could come up with a more pythonic approach:

```
def nearest(point, all_points):
    """Returns the closest point in all_points from the first parameter."""
    distance_from_point = functools.partial(distance, point)
    return min(all_points, key=distance_from_point)
```

The overall idea of the above solution is to build a partial function. This partial function takes a single parameter and returns the distance to the point given as parameter. This is could be re-written as `lambda other_point: distance(point, other_point)` but this is prettier.

Note the above function will raise `ValueError` if you call it with an empty list of points: `nearest(point, [])`. You can add an if for this case if necessary.

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that `min()` took a key function.

Comment: here is the problem im not sure if we are allowed to use the functools stuff yet since we so far have gotten to user defined functions in the textbook of Murah's Python Programming @FunkySayu

Comment: No worries, you can either use the first definition (2nd block of code) or use a lambda :)

Comment: @Gary: you can skip partial and write your own method which "closes" over `point`. The lambda does this.

Comment: @FunkySayu okay it works but if possible can you explain what is the `math.fabs(x0 - x1) + math.fabs(y0 - y1)` and 
`closest_point, best_distance = None, float("inf")`  does

Comment: `abs(x0 - x1) + abs(y0 - y1)` is called the Manhattan distance. It's just another distance than the Euclidean one. To use the euclidean, you can simply replace this by `math.sqrt((x0 - x1) ** 2 + (y0 - y1) ** 2)`.
To start the for loop we need to initialize 2 variables used to store the result. `closest_point` is the closest point of the list to the given one, and `best_distance` is its distance, avoiding to re-calculate it over and over. I just initialize them to `None` and `+infinity` ensuring at least one point will be better than the initialization.

Comment: @FunkySayu Thanks! btw you will be given credit. Professor requires this if we use StackoverFlow so

Answer (score 0):

Use `min()` with a `key` function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import math
from functools import partial


def distance_between_points(a, b):
    ax, ay = a
    bx, by = b
    return math.sqrt(pow(ax - bx, 2) + pow(ay - by, 2))


def nearest(point, more_points):
    '''
    Finds the nearest point to the base point
    '''
    distance_to_point = partial(distance_between_points, point)
    return min(more_points, key=distance_to_point)


point = (-4, 3)
my_points = [(10, 6), (1, 7), (6, 3), (1, 9)]
n = nearest(point, my_points)
print(n)
```